# Changing top tab bar background color when active

Tags: reactjs, react-native, colors, tabs, navigation

I have one top tab bar with two tabs on the screen which is created with React Navigation. I want to change the grey background colour to pink when tab is active, I have tried to find some solution, but can't find any. Is that even possible to do?

Any help is appreciated!

**Navigator.js**:

```
import { createMaterialTopTabNavigator } from "@react-navigation/material-top-tabs";
import { Tab1 } from "../pages/Tab1";
import { Tab2 } from "../pages/Tab2";

const TopTab = createMaterialTopTabNavigator();

export function TopTabNavigator() {
  return (
    <TopTab.Navigator
      screenOptions={{
        tabBarLabelStyle: {
          fontSize: 12,
          textTransform: "none",
        },
        tabBarItemStyle: {
          fontSize: 12,
          textTransform: "none",
          height: 30,
          minHeight: 10,
          backgroundColor: "#706c6c",
          borderRadius: 100,
          margin: 10,
          marginVertical: 10,
          padding: 3,
        },
        tabBarStyle: {
          backgroundColor: "transparent",
        },
        tabBarIndicator: () => null,
      }}
    >
      <TopTab.Screen name="Tab1" component={Tab1} />
      <TopTab.Screen name="Tab2" component={Tab2} />
    </TopTab.Navigator>
  );
}
```

**App.js**:

```
import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { TopTabNavigator } from "./src/routes/Navigator";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <TopTabNavigator />
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

This is how it looks like right now, only the text colour will change to some whiter colour when it is active.
[image: Top tab bar]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go, i created a snack so you can test it : [snack](https://snack.expo.dev/i2T1DsTaX)

you can basically play on the variable `isFocused` to change whatever you want